# Пунктуация в сложном предложении, объяснение запятой

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Грузная Лейла несла на голове расшитую цветными стеклянными бусинами шляпку-горшок и прятала нос в свалявшееся, словно ощипанное боа.*

Почему стоит запятая перед "словно"? Почему это не сравнительный оборот — "словно ощипанное"?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится между однородными определениями *свалявшееся* и *словно ощипанное*. Здесь нет сравнения между *свалявшийся* и *ощипанный*. Боа не свалялось как ощипанное, а было, во-первых, свалявшимся, а во-вторых — похожим на ощипанное.

Answer (score 0):

[**СЛОВНО**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1029438)
Союз, употребляется со словом "как" и без него (*разг.*)
**3. Как будто** (*прост.*)

*Что-то руки стали трястись по утрам… А выпьешь водочки, словно лучше*.
А.Островский

*Она побледнела, словно её что в сердце кольнуло, да так кольнуло, что она удивилась и долго потом размышляла о том, что бы это значило.*
И. С. Тургенев

Так сказано в словаре Ушакова. Толковый словарь [**Ожегова**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/223334) называет "словно" частицей, но смысл от этих разночтений не меняется: *словно ощипанное* не является сравнительным оборотом.

**Грузная Лейла несла на голове расшитую цветными стеклянными бусинами шляпку-горшок и прятала нос в свалявшееся, словно** [ = будто, как будто, точно] **ощипанное боа.**

Answer (score 0):

Грузная Лейла несла на голове расшитую цветными стеклянными бусинами шляпку-горшок и прятала нос в **свалявшееся, словно  ощипанное боа.**

Сравнить: Огромный яркий диск луны показался краем над дальним лесом, на серебрившуюся траву упали **черные, будто нарисованные углем тени.** [Николай Дежнев. Принцип неопределенности (2009)]

Обороты с союзами СЛОВНО, БУДТО в этих предложениях **оформлены как однородные члены.**

Союзы СЛОВНО, БУДТО, КАК БУДТО часто имеют значение **уподобления**,  в этом случае их  можно убрать из предложения без изменения его структуры;  поэтому обороты с этими союзами обычно не обособляются. Например: **Словно белою косынкой** Повязалася сосна.